# onClick Event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

onclick event is not working. While I click on the check box nothing appear .
Here is my code:

```js
function showHide() 
{
    var checkbox1=document.getElementById("iconbox");
    var hiddeninputs=document.getElementsByClassName("hidden");
    for (var i=0;i!=hiddeninputs.length;i++){
        if(checkbox1.checked){
            hiddeninputs[i].style.display="block";          
        }
    }   
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" name="form1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="iconbox" id="iconbox"onclick="showHide()"/>
      <label for="iconbox">Manage your header</label>
      <input type="text" name="icon1" id="icon1" class="hidden">
      <input type="text" name="icon2" id="icon2" class="hidden">
</form>
```

Comment: write : `onClick="return showHide()"`

Comment: It works, what did you expect? If you want to hide/show input-text you don't have to use `class="hidden"` to hide and `style="display: block"` to show, but you have to decide: using add/remove class or change style.

Comment: @SorangwalaAbbasali That would change absolutely nothing.

Comment: still not working

Comment: What you have should work (and does: https://jsfiddle.net/1867ow5n/). If it's not working for you, check the console for errors. Also note that the `showHide()` function *should not* be placed within a jQuery document.ready handler, as it needs to be in global scope due to the use of the `onclick` event attribute - which is an issue in itself.

Comment: If you click on the "Run code snippet" in the question, you'll notice that the code you have shown (+ the CSS rule to initially hide the text fields) works fine. Please edit the code in the question so that it matches what you have and reproduces the problem.

Comment: its works for me .thanks to you people

Answer (score 0):

You hide your element with class="hidden" and you try to show them with display="block". 
You should EITHER hide with display="none" and show with display="block" 
OR hide with class="hidden" and show with remove class "hidden" with the remove function of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the one are you expecting?

```js
function showHide() {
  var checked = document.getElementById("iconbox").checked;
  var hiddeninputs = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden");
  for (var i = 0; i != hiddeninputs.length; i++)
    hiddeninputs[i].style.display = (checked) ? "block" : "none";
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" name="form1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="iconbox" id="iconbox" onclick="showHide()" />
  <label for="iconbox">Manage your header</label>
  <input type="text" name="icon1" id="icon1" class="hidden">
  <input type="text" name="icon2" id="icon2" class="hidden">
</form>
```